# OpenWrt UDP Socket stops working after some time - PHP uHTTPd

Tags: php, sockets, udp, openwrt

I installed OpenWrt in my router for implementing home automation. I am using PHP with uHTTPd server.

UDP packets generated from PHP stops working after some time but the PHP is not throwing any errors. I tried restarting uHTTPd and PHP, but not solving the issue.

But when I unplug and plug the network cable of the target device, it will again starts working.

This problem only occurs when I send packets from OpenWrt, it is working fine when I send packets from my laptop.